# How to disable giving focus to controls behind another control?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I have a form layout like this:

- button1
- panel1

  - button2
- panel2

  - button3

`Dock = DockStyle.Fill` is set on both panels. When the form is shown, both panels are hidden. When button1  is clicked, panel1 is shown. When button2 is clicked, panel2 is shown. Now, the only controls the user can see or click are button3 and panel2. But they can give focus to button1 or button2 by pressing tab.

The click event of the buttons:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.BringToFront();
        }
```

The click event of the back buttons:

```
    private void back_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }
```

How can I prevent this?

Also, why is did I choose this design? Because in reality, there are lots of panels, many of them can be shown in multiple ways, and have a back button on them. So when the back button is pressed, the only thing to do is to hide the current panel, and there is no need to know which panel was shown before.

Comment: You could set `Enabled` to `false` on buttons or panels you don't want to receive input focus.

Comment: How are you hiding the other panels? By changing z-order or visibility?

Comment: show some code related to your question.

Comment: @adv12 I'm not doing that because the point of this design is to not store the panel that made the currently visible panel visible. The back button hides the topmost panel, and the previous one is already there.

Comment: This question is poor because it's vague and doesn't show us the actions on the button clicks.  Sefe is probably right; you're likely only changing z-order, so the other controls are still "visible", and can get focus.  Without seeing any code, I'd recommend that your button click event handlers should turn all panels invisible, and then only turn the one panel you're interested in visible.  This might solve your problem.  But, since I don't see any code at all, for all I know, rebooting will solve your problem.

Comment: I think this may be a situation where you have to give up on the "elegant" solution because it doesn't actually work and do things the "ugly" way that does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by choosing another way. This is the code I added to the form:

```
    private List<Panel> Pages { get; } = new List<Panel>();

    public Panel CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            return Pages.Last();
        }
    }
    public void ShowPage(Panel page)
    {
        Pages.Add(page);

        foreach (var panel in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            if (panel.Dock == DockStyle.Fill)
                panel.Visible = false;
        }

        page.Visible = true;
    }
    public void HidePage()
    {
        if (CurrentPage != null)
            CurrentPage.Visible = false;

        Pages.RemoveAt(Pages.Count - 1);

        if (CurrentPage != null)
            CurrentPage.Visible = true;
    }
```